How to link dlls to each other in CMake?
For msvc, to resolve the problem when two DLLs dependent on each other, it generateS an exp file for linking. But in CMake, if I write
target_link_libraries (A PUBLIC B)
target_link_libraries (B PUBLIC A)

there will be an cyclic dependency error. How to write CMake for this case?

That answer seems to target the same problem. Have you tried it?
